# How to solve laravel file_input_error

Tags: laravel-5

When I log in, this error show ->

```
i already give permission to src/storage
```

`file_put_contents(/var/www/html/catalog/src/storage/framework/cache/55/f9/55f98a9ae16c0c5f7c41c2f6d5435d3f37274a71): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Create `cache` directory in storage directory, and give him read & write permission to it. Error saying that your `cache` directory does not exists